# Bootstrap nav pills expand

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this small sample of bootstrap nav-pills I have got the dropdown part to work but trying to figure if there is a way to make it open and close like an accordion instead of the dropdown/

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look here http://www.bootply.com/wbvWCthDHq

Comment: that's not what I am looking for the nav-stacked works for me I want instead of a drop down it expands to show the sub links

Comment: If I read correcty, what you are trying to do, is a collapsible submenu?

Comment: @CrisMVP3200 correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your submenu to have an accordion behaviour, instead of using dropdown components, is better to use **collapse** components.

In the case of your code, you need to specify your submenu element with the class `.collapse`, and an ID

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, your need to specify the data attributes in the element you will be using, to toggle on and off your submenu.

```
<li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" href="javascript:void(0)">
        Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <!-- Content of your collapsible element -->
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Here is the full code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" href="javascript:void(0)">
            Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
```

Here your can see it in action. Also, I've added some custom CSS to make your submenu visually looking better:

```css
#demo ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#demo ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#demo ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" href="javascript:void(0)">
      Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**See also**: [Bootstrap Collapse (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)